# MySQL add extra column on result based on another query

Tags: mysql

I have following Problem

```
SELECT * from map_user_sticker WHERE map_user_sticker.user_id = 7;
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | sticker_id |
+----+---------+------------+
| 35 |       7 |         55 |
|  3 |       7 |         30 |
| 32 |       7 |         49 |
| 33 |       7 |         52 |
| 34 |       7 |         43 |
| 36 |       7 |         50 |
+----+---------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT * FROM sticker;
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
| id | word                                             |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
| 40 | I love Sonal                                     |
| 41 | Add User to Database                             |
| 39 | This is a dream Project                          |
| 33 | Narendra Sisodiya                                |
| 34 | Sourabh Parmar                                   |
| 30 | Sonal Sisodiya                                   |
| 42 | I love India                                     |
| 43 | I love Linux                                     |
| 44 | I hate Congress                                  |
| 45 | I love jQuery                                    |
| 48 | Modi will be the PM                              |
| 47 | Ramdev Baba is my Super Hero                     |
| 49 | हिन्दी से प्यार है |
| 50 | Linux is better then Windows                     |
| 52 | I am from Sehore                                 |
| 55 | I have 2 little kids - sadu and sonu             |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I basically want to generate Result like

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------+----------+
| id | word                                             |  present |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 40 | I love Sonal                                     |  0       |
| 41 | Add User to Database                             |  0       |
| 39 | This is a dream Project                          |  0       |
| 33 | Narendra Sisodiya                                |  0       |
| 34 | Sourabh Parmar                                   |  0       |
| 30 | Sonal Sisodiya                                   |  1       |
| 42 | I love India                                     |  0       |
| 43 | I love Linux                                     |  1       |
| 44 | I hate Congress                                  |  0       |
| 45 | I love jQuery                                    |  0       |
| 48 | Modi will be the PM                              |  0       |
| 47 | Ramdev Baba is my Super Hero                     |  0       |
| 49 | हिन्दी से प्यार है                                      |   1      |
| 50 | Linux is better then Windows                     |   1      |
| 52 | I am from Sehore                                 |   1      |
| 55 | I have 2 little kids - sadu and sonu             |   1      |
+----+--------------------------------------------------+----------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please Help me !!
I want to generate a extra column called  "present", based on following condition 
    If sticker_id from query1 == id from query 2 then present = 1
    else present = 0

Comment: Try to use LEFT JOIN to get result from referenced tables, then try to check `present` value with an IF condition.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer

    SELECT sticker.id, word, (IF(map_user_sticker.user_id  = 7, 1, 0)) AS present 
    FROM sticker LEFT JOIN map_user_sticker 
    ON sticker.id = map_user_sticker.sticker_id;
    GROUP BY sticker.id

Comment: LEFT JOIN is creating duplicates !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the Answer I was wanted to get !

Answer 1 -

```
SELECT s.* , IF(FIND_IN_SET(7,(GROUP_CONCAT(m.user_id))) != 0 , 1,0) as present, COUNT(m.user_id) as totalUsers 
FROM sticker s   
LEFT JOIN map_user_sticker m  
ON s.id = m.sticker_id 
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer 2 -

```
SELECT id,word, (case when 7 in (select user_id from map_user_sticker WHERE map_user_sticker.sticker_id=sticker.id) then 1 else 0 end) as present 
from sticker;
```

I don,t know which one is fast and better

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id,word,
case(when id in (select sticker_id from map_user_sticker) then 1 else 0 end) 
as present from sticker;
```

Comment: it should be "(case when" and not "case(when" , it also work but I have to compare both results.

Comment: Yep true, I mistaken with Sql Server syntax. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: but still,I want something like this - 
    `select id,word, 
    (case when 7 in (select user_id from map_user_sticker WHERE map_user_sticker.sticker_id=sticker.id) then 1 else 0 end)  as present 
    from sticker;`

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help:

`SELECT sticker.id, sticker.word, (IF(sticker_id IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS present FROM sticker LEFT JOIN map_user_sticker ON (sticker.id = map_user_sticker.sticker_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT s.*, IF(COUNT(m.sticker_id) > 0, 1, 0) present FROM sticker s
  LEFT JOIN map_user_sticker m
    ON s.id = m.sticker_id
GROUP BY
  s.id;
```

---

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT s.*, IF(m.sticker_id IS NULL, 0, 1) present FROM sticker s
  LEFT JOIN map_user_sticker m
    ON s.id = m.sticker_id
WHERE m.user_id = 7;
```

Comment: Not working.
`SELECT s.* , m.* FROM sticker s   LEFT JOIN map_user_sticker m     ON s.id = m.sticker_id ;`

which return something like
`| 52 | I am from Sehore                                 |   29 |      10 |         52 |
| 52 | I am from Sehore                                 |   37 |       7 |         52 |
`
Now Group By id, will remove second entry. actually both entry are important. Sometimes I want to query in the context of user_id = 10 Or sometimes I want to query in context of user_id = 7. So value of column `present` varies.

Comment: Thanks, I have answered and got two methods